# SQL Case Statement Returns 0 When Used as Dividend

Tags: sql, case, divide-by-zero

I have a case statement in SQL that works perfectly by itself (returns an expected non-zero number), but when I try to use it to divide another expression, it gives me a divide by 0 error. It is a very basic sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 0 end) statement. Basically, this is what I have:

```
select 

sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 0 end) as [Value 1],

(sum(case value2 when 99999 then valueB else 0 end)) / (sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 0 end)) as [Value 2]
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is not working? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: make sure the `else` part of the denominator is something other than `0`

Comment: What do you get when you select distinct value1?  Are there any records with a value that isn't 99999?  If so, then you're going to be dividing by 0.

Comment: Where are you selecting from? Can you write the full query? You might have to change the dividend to `(select sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 0 end) from [Table])` otherwise it will be evaluated on an individual basis and, as @Jim said, anytime you get a value that isn't 99999 is will try to divide by 0

Comment: So only SUM(99999 or 0) ?? Is very hard guess what is happening without a schema. Can you try set a demo in [sqlFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1b72/2)

Comment: I am surprised that you are not asking ***how*** to fix it, but rather ***why*** it's not working?  It seems to me that you know exactly why already.  You even tagged your question correctly (`divide-by-zero`) :) So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically covered by the comments but your dividend else needs to not be 0. So if it is something other than 99999 then you would have 0/1 = 0 instead of 0/0 = divide by zero error.

```
select 

sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 0 end) as [Value 1],

(sum(case value2 when 99999 then valueB else 0 end)) / (sum(case value1 when 99999 then valueA else 1 end)) as [Value 2]
```

Comment: i dont think `else 1` works, because if you have several values A <>  99999 you still get a division

Comment: changing it to else 1 fixes the else statement to work, if he has a value other than 99999 he will always get 0 as a result. Though if valueA variable is 0 he could still get a divide by zero error when value1 = 99999.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a divide by zero error under certain circumstances.  Here, I changed your fields to variables and set them to the conditions where your line produces an error.  Simply trap for a zero value denominator.

```
DECLARE @value1 int
DECLARE @valueA int

DECLARE @value2 int
DECLARE @valueB int

SET @value2 = 99999
SET @valueB = 13

SET @value1 = 99998
SET @valueA = 7

SELECT
    sum(case @value1 when 99999 then @valueA else 0 end) as [Value 1],

    (sum(case @value2 when 99999 then @valueB else 0 end)) AS [Numerator],
    (sum(case @value1 when 99999 then @valueA else 0 end)) as [Denominator], 

    --(sum(case @value2 when 99999 then @valueB else 0 end)) / (sum(case @value1 when 99999 then @valueA else 0 end)) as [Value 2], --your line that may return an error
    [My Value 2] = CASE WHEN (sum(case @value1 when 99999 then @valueA else 0 end)) = 0 THEN
        --'undefined'
        0
    ELSE
        --CONVERT(nvarchar(max), 
            (sum(case @value2 when 99999 then @valueB else 0 end)) / (sum(case @value1 when 99999 then @valueA else 0 end))
        --  )
    END
```

Comment: good point, unless OP is 100% certain that @valueA will be a non-zero value then checking the value of the Denominator would be a good idea.